# Declaration of a doubly linked list in a structure

Tags: c, struct, doubly-linked-list

Is this the correct procedure in declaring a doubly linked list within a structure.I'm using the structure to read in a text file if this has any relevance.

```
#define MAX 20
//struct to order contactList
struct contact
{
    string firstName[MAX],lastName[MAX],email[MAX],companyName[MAX];
    long phoneNum[MAX];
    struct listelement *link
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;

};
```

Comment: Does this compile?  That's always a good start in checking correctness.

Comment: what are `listelement` and `node`?

Comment: @SteveTownsend Only in the same way not being on fire is a good start on checking health.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not.  Normally, you'd use `struct contact *next; struct contact *prev;` since the items in the list are (probably) `struct contact` and not `struct node`.

Hence, I'd expect to see:

```
#define MAX 20
//struct to order contactList
struct contact
{
    string              firstName[MAX];
    string              lastName[MAX];
    string              email[MAX];
    string              companyName[MAX];
    long                phoneNum[MAX];    /* 20 phone numbers per contact — wow! */
    struct listelement *link;             /* Semi-colon added.  What is this for? */
    struct contact     *next;
    struct contact     *prev;
};
```

The email element of the structure is too short (my main email address wouldn't fit, for example; you need 32 bytes at least, I suggest).  That's an awful lot of phone numbers for a single contact.  Also, `long` will not store all 10-digit phone numbers.

It is not clear what the `link` element is for.  It presumably is part of a singly-linked list involving these structures.